# JSP can't 'see' local resource files (css, img, js)

Tags: jsp, tomcat

With no changes on my end, my Tomcat (Mochahost) application all of a sudden is reporting 404s for the local css,js,img files.  I have tried ALL forms of syntax for including them.  IF I use the CDN for bootstrap, it does work fine...but I have my own css file that I have to use.
You can see the issue here:
http://dsdpdcoaching.com/

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this to my filter.  Did my hosting company add some type of security/patch to cause me to start needing this?

```
if(uri.matches(".*[css|jpg|png|gif|js]")){
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }
```